# Bootstrap - image keeps shifting out of place when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using bootstrap and am having a problem with my image shifting out of place when I resize my browser. The background image that is holding my image and text doesn't seem to be scaling either. when I maximise my browser everything is in place and perfect. As you can see in the first image that is where my problem is. The second image is how it looks maximised and how it should look with all screen sizes. Any help appreciated!

[image]

[image]

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<link href=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">
<link href=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="images/theater.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>

   <body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>

        <div id="rainbow"><img alt="rainbow gradient" src=
        "images/rainbow.png"></div>

        <div id="header">
            <!--home-->

            <p id="logo"><img alt="Bethan Rainforth a comedic dancer" src=
            "images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="nav-bar">
            <nav class="nav">

                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="gray" href="work.html">Work</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="gray" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="gray" href="hireme.html">Hire!</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="about-me row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img alt="Bethan Rainforth" class="img-responsive" id="pic" src=
                "images/pic.png">

                <p class="about-text">I am a physical comedian, continuously
                being inspired by comical characters and exaggerated
                movement. I fuse elements of dance and theatre to create
                performances that are somewhat over-the-top, and
                outrageous. I use locking technique as a foundation build
                and produce uproarious performances suitable for an
                eclectic audience. I aim to leave audience members feeling
                uplifted, swimming in their own tears of laughter,
                momentarily forgetting any worries or woes.</p>
            </div><!--End of col-md-12 about me-->
        </div><!--End of about me row-->
    </div><!--End of about me wrapper-->


  /********************************
    Body of page
  *********************************/

     html,
     body {
background-image: url(images/background.png);
margin: 0 auto;
   }

#container{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
 /********************************
 Header
*********************************/
#rainbow img{
margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

#logo img {
width: 320px;
 }

 /********************************
 Navigation
 *********************************/
 nav a {
font-family: Hobo Std;
padding: 50px;
}
 ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
 nav {
text-align: center;
margin-left: 20px;


 }

 a {
text-decoration: none;
 }
 nav li {
 display: inline;
 width: 150px;
 }
.gray,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:active {
color: #a5a5a5;
text-decoration: none;
 }

#home {
background-image: url(images/pinkpaint.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
width: 30px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #000;
}

   ul.list-inline{
  margin-top: 25px;
  }

 /********************************
 About Me
*********************************/

 img#pic {
width: 260px;
float: left;
margin-left: 54px;
margin-top: 74px;

 }

.about-me {
background-image: url(images/border.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: center center;
width: 730px;
height: 490px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
 }


p.about-text{
color: #7ca5d2;
font-family: hobo std;
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 35px;
margin: 75px;

 }
```

Comment: used to this css img{vertical-align:top;}

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is adding 74px to the top of the image:

```
img#pic {
width: 260px;
float: left;
margin-left: 54px;
margin-top: 74px;
}
```

Try removing the margin-top code and see what happens. If needed for desktop, you can add a media query so that it is removed when resized. For example:

```
@media and (max-width:700px) {
   img#pic {
      margin-top: 0;
   }
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: It worked when i resized but now when I expand the browser the image flows outside the border. I just want it to scale with the border no matter the screen size.

Comment: It most likely flowed outside the border because the margin-left: 54px was not being applied, maybe you removed it or excluded it somewhere. There are more efficient ways of doing this other than the example I showed you, and I could go over all of them but that wouldn't help as you wouldn't learn from me providing the full solutions. Play around with the media query a bit and see what you can come up with. Trust me, you'll feel great defeating a problem and it'll motivate you next time you're stuck. I know you can do it ^.^ If not, come back and we'll help you out.

Comment: Just think of WHY something is happening when you resize it, then think of how you can fix that using CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did find a solution. I decided to get rid of the background image and just use a border since it wouldn't make that much of a difference and now the image is staying in place! I just need to figure out how to get the border to scale because right now when the browser is small I have to scroll right to see the entire border.

Comment: Ah, that would most likely be caused from a set width of the div that has that border, which would cause the overflow on smaller screen resolutions. For example, if the div with the border is 700px wide and you get on a screen that is 400px wide, it would give you that option to scroll right to see the rest of the div. Look through your code, you have a set width somewhere. Catch it if you can, and resize it on smaller screens.